# Switching Windows and Linux Partitions

Tags: windows, partitioning

So basically I want to copy my windows partitions /dev/sdb1 and /dev/sdb2 to /dev/sda3 and /dev/sda4

I want to then move my linux partition of /dev/sda5 to /dev/sdb

Basically /deb/sdb is my primary drive (WHY IS IT READ AS sdb if its the primary?)

So I want to move linux to my primary drive so I have faster read/write speeds.

If I just go and copy the windows partition and the linux partition and move them and then reinstall the bootloader will it all work? Or is this a huge no no.

Basically I need my windows partition to be where the linux one is and vise versa. I am fluent enough to go and do this all on my own. BUT I DO NOT KNOW IF IT WILL EVEN WORK.

Will this work? Is there already a good tutorial I can follow or should i just go manually copy partitions and move them around?

Comment: This is not a full answer, but I think "sdb" is called that because of hardwired physical reasons. You can boot from any of sda/sdb/etc. With moving partitions, I'm not sure how the Windows side works (I think it might be picky), but as for Linux, you'd also need to modify `/etc/fstab`. Have a search for this, it essentially tells Linux which partitions to mount where.

Comment: Thanks for your words, but not to sure what to take on it.

Yes technically the bootloader can be placed anywhere but for obvious reasons (windows is evil) its easier to put it on sdb (for the moment)

anyone else have any advice for me? 

if Sparhawk was more sure i would start manually doing it all.

p.s. a link would help :D

Comment: When I migrated to half SSD and half spindle HD, I used clonezilla to clone the disk. If it's a physical problem with the drive, can you clone it, then physical swap them? Probably the simplest.

Comment: Oh wow fast reply, that one is quite helpful, I forgot about how nice clonezilla is. I will start working on that now.

Again a super strong confirmation that this WILL WORK AND WINDOWS WONT CRY LIKE A BABY would be nice.

99% of what im doing on my PC atm involves rewriting to the disk so i must get my linux partition as close as possible to the center. And also on /dev/sdb




EDIT: I think its more likely that sdb is the primary drive and that sda is not damaged. because the speed loss isnt GIANT GIANT.

Comment: Yeah, well, I dual boot too, and when I was trying to migrate, I was failing, because I wasn't copying a non-partition ~500 bytes boot code before the first partition! However, using clonezilla worked fine for me anyway. Can you just test it and see? However, I think we can never guarantee that Windows won't cry like a baby! :)

Answer (score 0):

First, assignment of the `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb` identification is done by the kernel. If both disks are controlled by a single chipset, then typically `/dev/sda` will be attached to a lower-numbered port than `/dev/sdb`. (Ports are often numbered on motherboards or at least identified in documentation.) Sometimes BIOS settings can influence which device gets which moniker. If the two are controlled by different chipsets, the assignment will depend on the order in which the two chipsets' drivers register their devices. (This order can vary between boots in some cases.) In the case of removable disks, of course, the order in which they're plugged in can be a factor, too. There are also exceptions to these rules, such as if you explicitly adjust assignments with udev rules, but that's getting into pretty obscure stuff. Note that the rules for what device gets a given assignment have nothing to do with the importance of a device for you or even with where Linux "lives."

It's unclear what you mean by a "primary" drive, but most likely meanings do *not* guarantee superior performance. Disk performance is determined mainly by hardware -- ideally the bottleneck will be on the disk platter itself, but it can be in the interface technology or elsewhere. Moving Linux from a spinning hard disk to an SSD is likely to improve its performance. Moving it from one spinning disk to another might or might not improve performance, but to know if it will help you'll need to examine the disks' specification sheets and study the disk controller(s) at your disposal. In many cases you'll get optimal performance by spreading Linux *across* two or more disks in a [RAID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redundant_Array_of_Independent_Disks) or [striped LVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) setup.

Moves such as you suggest are certainly possible, but there are a hundred things that can go wrong. ***Undertake this task only if you have adequate backups!!!!*** I'm afraid that I don't have a link to a suitable tutorial, although I'm sure something like that must exist somewhere on the Web (and maybe on this very site). It's not a trivial task to undertake, or even to write about, so I can't simply whip up some instructions for you in five minutes. It will involve using any of dozens of data-copying tools, perhaps using a partition resizing tool, and probably re-installing your boot loader.

I recommend that you first learn more about your disk hardware to be sure that such a change will actually provide you with a real benefit. Certainly you've presented no evidence that this will be the case, so my best recommendation, given what ***I*** know of your situation, is to leave it alone -- there's wisdom to the saying *don't fix what ain't broken.*